# Angular 2: how to correctly change the template's variable via service?

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I can't dynamically change the state of HTML element, using some property of component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home-page',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    styleUrls:['home.component.scss'],
    providers:[AuthService]

})

export class HomeComponent  implements OnInit {
    public isAuth: boolean;

    constructor(private auth: AuthService) {

   ngOnInit() {
      this.isAuth = this.auth.temp;
      console.log(this.isAuth);
  }
}
```

My AuthService is here:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    public activeUser:ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject();
    dataBoolean$ = this.activeUser.asObservable();

    set signIn(val: boolean) {
        console.log("sign-in");

        Observable.of(val).subscribe
        (
            res => {
                this.activeUser.next(res);
                console.log("SIGNIN >>>>> ", res);
                this.temp = res;
            }
        );
        console.log("temp", this.temp);
    }
}
```

OK, when I click on button signIn() code works properly: I see console's output from service and then from component.

But in my template I have this:

```
<button [disabled]="isAuth">Pull</button>
```

I consider that when Observable emits new value, I get this in component and new property of component should be displayed in template immediately.

Even with this way:

```
setInterval(() => {
            this.isAuth = !this.isAuth;
            console.log(this.isAuth);
        }, 2000);
```

Button can't change her state.

But it's not true or I do something wrong.

Comment: `isAuth` is assigned only once. I guess you need to bind data from service property instead, `<button [disabled]="auth.temp">`. Or bind an observable `<button [disabled]="auth.dataBoolean$ | async">`.

Comment: In order to check this I have added 

setInterval(() => {
            this.isAuth = !this.isAuth;
            console.log(this.isAuth);
        }, 2000);
but my button doesn't change her state.

Comment: Looks strange. Can you replicate the issue in plunker?

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 **change detector** is using `zones` to *detect* changes. For example, if you want to use timer (like `setInterval`) you have to do it in this way:

```
setInterval(() => {
     this.isAuth = !this.isAuth;
     console.log(this.isAuth);
     this.cd.detectChanges();
}, 2000);
```

What is `this.cd` property? It is an injected `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
constructor(private cd : ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

But why you have to do it? Because in Angular 2, change detectors are responsible for telling Ng2 when to update the view.

There you can read a lot about it:

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Actually, it is clear from the question that `setInterval` is executed in component class, so it should trigger change detection without `detectChanges()`. That's the part of zone magic.

Comment: The part of code in any timer - setTimeout / setInterval is not in angular zone. Angular2 will not detect change on his own.

Comment: Zone.js patches all global async functions, including setTimeout. That's the way how it detects changes without polling or digest cycles. Component classes are zoned. See [this example with `setTimeout`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#add-a-hero-and-reset-the-form), that's pretty exhaustive explanation of the behaviour.

Comment: You are right, thanks. It didn't works, because my parent component has change detection set on OnPush. Maybe the author also has this issue :)